# qBitTorrent-nox (seemingly) randomly timeouting with no logs

Tags: web-server, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, bugs

qBitTorrent's web UI is (seemingly) randomly, with no warning, returning a timeout; the website will not load and almost all features on the UI will not function; this occurs both on the port, from localhost, and on the domain name. No other services can connect with it.

The logs contain (I think) no useful info, just a listening alert: https://pastebin.com/raw/ARrXnb6g (ip and port removed)

Below is my UptimeKuma log for qBitTorrent. The uptime is clearly not great.
[image: Uptime Kuma]

Here is my systemctl file:

```
[Unit]
Description=qBittorrent
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=qbittorrent
Group=qbittorrent
UMask=007
ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox -d --webui-port=7080
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

CPU usage and ram usage is minimal, 8gb 64bit pi 4 with idle 4gb ram usage and ~10% cpu. My pi is set to restart at midnight every day. qBitTorrent does have a lot of torrents on it though; about 400. Using systemctl restart, start, or running the command, takes a very long time to do anything (multiple minutes).  All other services running on pi work when qBitTorrent is down, except the ones that rely on it.

It's proving very difficult to bugfix this issue as it appears to be random, but I have tried:

Reinstalling qbittorrent & libtorrent (I have avoided purge, out of fear of it removing my settings), restarting qBitTorrent every time it timeouts, etc.

Sorry if this isn't the right fit for this stack, this is my first post here.

Thanks!